# onLoadFinished not called after coming back from a HOME button press

Tags: android, fragment

When using a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` to download data from a web service, if I press the HOME button in the middle of the loading process and then enter the app again, the onLoadFinished() method is not called. My fragment is calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onActivityCreated()` and it also calls `getLoaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this)` in the same method (as is recommended).

While testing, I see that when coming back to the fragment `onActivityCreated()` is not called so this may be why `onLoadFinished()` is not called. But where else to put the `initLoader()` method? I've read in several places that it should not be called in `onResume()`.

So, any ideas? I have a lot of loaders in various screens in my app and I need to solve this issue in an elegant way.

Comment: Where did you read that `initloader` should not be called in `onResume()` because that is exactly what is required to workaround a framework bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63179

Comment: @faizal I really don't remember. I have moved away from using loaders a long time ago. A lot of expert devs recommend from experience against using Loaders for fetching network data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After looking at Issue 14944 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14944), I solved the issue by overriding `onStartLoading()` in my custom `AsyncTaskLoader` and call `forceLoad()`.

An even better solution is to create a custom parent `AsyncTaskLoader` that looks like this (taken from a suggestion by alexvem from the link above):

```
public abstract class AsyncLoader<D> extends AsyncTaskLoader<D> {

    private D data;

    public AsyncLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(D data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
            return;
        }

        this.data = data;

        super.deliverResult(data);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (data != null) {
            deliverResult(data);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || data == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
         // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        // Ensure the loader is stopped
        onStopLoading();

        data = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved for me by overrriding onStartLoading() and calling forceLoad() in it.