# LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished() is not called after load finishes

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I created a loader that descends from `AsyncTaskLoader`. It works 99% of the time, but there's an edge case where `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished()` is not called after `AsyncTaskLoader.loadInBackground()` returns successfully. I don't know what's different in the edge case but I can't think of any reason why the loader would fail between these two calls. Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474756/onloadfinished-not-called-after-coming-back-from-a-home-button-press

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. :-/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is important how you run your Loader:

You can run it first time by `activity.getLoaderManager().initLoader()` method, but you can't run it second time like this.

You need to use `activity.getLoaderManager().restartLoader()` method for further. You also can use this method right from the start, because it will init your loader if it was not initialized yet.

It is highly recommended to start loaders in Activity's `onCreate` method.

If you need to start your loader from somewhere else, and call to `onLoadFinished` does not happen (for example, after you rotate the screen), place call to `getLoaderManager()` in `onCreate` instead, it can really [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166363/loadercallbacks-onloadfinished-not-called-if-orientation-change-happens-during-a/47297350#47297350).